# Portal 2 - Co-op Gesture Test Issues

Tags: portal-2

In Portal 2 when I start the co-op mode I can't get past the gesture test.

It shows me the prompt that tells me I have to press <kbd>Q</kbd> in order to gesture, but when I press the key all I see on screen is a red circle with a slash through it. I checked my backpack and sure enough it doesn't have any gesture. Is that what the symbol signifies? Do I need to unlock a gesture in singleplayer mode first to play co-op?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what the red circle would indicate, but it took me a minute to figure out that holding down the gesture key opens a radial menu with icons around the perimeter. (It took a minute at first because there's only one icon at the beginning... not much of a circle)  Moving the mouse towards the icon (in this case, up) while holding the key down and then letting go of the gesture key executes the gesture.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It works! I didn't realize at all that the thing was a menu interface! I feel stupidly enlightened! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to try:

- Are you sure you aren't pressing <kbd>A</kbd> instead of <kbd>Q</kbd> due to Azerty / Qwerty diffenerces?
- Have you tried assigning another key to this? Are you holding any other keys simultaneously?
- Have you tried looking at a different angle or standing in a different place?
- Have you tried joining again or restarting Portal 2?

If this doesn't help you might need to contact the Steam Customer Support...